# Memory copy and delete failed in C programming

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm trying to split an randomly generated array in C. When I tried to print it out and check the data, it will always print the last chunk of data for me. And I will receive an free failure and the end of the running time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 100
#define CHUNK_COUNT 4


int main(){
    long int * array = (long int *) malloc(sizeof(long int) *N);
    int i;
    int chunkSize = N/CHUNK_COUNT;
    long int ** data = (long int **) malloc(sizeof(long int*) *CHUNK_COUNT);
    srandom(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i< N; i++)
    {
        array[i] = random();
    }

    for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("%ld ",array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i< CHUNK_COUNT; i++)
    {
        long int *subArr = (long int*) malloc(sizeof(long int)*chunkSize);
        memcpy(subArr, &array[i*chunkSize], chunkSize*sizeof(long int));
        data[i] =subArr;
        free((void *)subArr);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < CHUNK_COUNT; i++)
    {
        printf("Array %d: \n",i);
        for(int j =0;j< chunkSize; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 ) {printf("[ ");}
            printf("%ld ",data[i][j]);
            if (j==chunkSize-1) {printf("]\n");}
        }       
    }

    free((void *) array);
    for (i = 0; i < CHUNK_COUNT; i++)
    {
        free((void*)data[i]);
    }
    free((void *) data);



}
```

When I debugging my code, I can see the chunk index is correct, but it will always print the last chunk of the entire data. However, when I print it inside the for loop that I memcpy long integers, it will print the correct results. Also, I received this error:

> *** Error in `./test': double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000000ec4370 ***
>   Aborted (core dumped)

When I use gnu99 to compile it:

`gcc -std=gnu99 -o test testSplit.c -g`

And when I run it in gdb, I could only get an `__GI_raise` error. Anyone has ideas?

Comment: `data[i] =subArr; free((void *)subArr);` Doesn't that look wrong to you? Freeing something that you have saved a reference to and will use later?

Comment: @kaylumI'm freeing `subArr` after I assign it to the `data[i]`, will that also destroy the reference to that? So how come it will only maintain the last chunk? I don't get it.

Comment: If you copy down the address of your house and then destroy your house does having the address still allow you to access the house? Accessing freed memory is Undefined Behaviour. UB means the result is unpredicatable (could crash, could return wrong values, could even return right values sometimes!).

Comment: I see what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters already showed the error (keeping the adress instead of the actual content) let me show a possible solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 100
#define CHUNK_COUNT 4


int main()
{
  // don't cast malloc() in C (you may do in O++)
  long int *array = malloc(sizeof(long int) * N);
  int i;
  int chunkSize = N / CHUNK_COUNT;
  long int **data = malloc(sizeof(long int *) * CHUNK_COUNT);
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    array[i] = rand();
  }

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%ld ", array[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
  for (i = 0; i < CHUNK_COUNT; i++) {
    // no need for a temporary array , you can use the destination directly
    data[i] = malloc(sizeof(long int) * chunkSize);
    memcpy(data[i], &array[i * chunkSize], chunkSize * sizeof(long int));
  }

  for (i = 0; i < CHUNK_COUNT; i++) {
    printf("Array %d: \n", i);
    for (int j = 0; j < chunkSize; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        printf("[ ");
      }
      printf("%ld ", data[i][j]);
      if (j == chunkSize - 1) {
        printf("]\n");
      }
    }
  }

  free(array);
  for (i = 0; i < CHUNK_COUNT; i++) {
    // no need for casting here
    free(data[i]);
  }
  free(data);
}
```

It is almost always a good idea to keep things as simple as possible (but not simpler).